# Cannot supress PySpark warnings

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, suppress-warnings

I am having some issues with trying to suppress pyspark warnings, specifically pandas on spark API. What I currently have:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=Warning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pyspark.pandas as

%%capture
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .master("local[32]")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "150g")
    .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "40g")\
    .config("spark.python.worker.memory", "1g")\
    .config("spark.num.executors","(3x-2)")\
    .config("spark.num.executor.cores","5")\
    .config("spark.driver.cores", "5")\
    .appName("Analysis")\
    .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

Then followed by the actual data analysis:

```
spark.catalog.clearCache()
enc = ps.read_parquet("/example_path/")
enc.columns = [i.lower() for i in enc.columns]
print(enc.en_end_date.min())
print(enc.en_end_date.max())
enc['year'] = enc.en_end_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y') if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)
enc['month'] = enc.en_end_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m') if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)
enc['day'] = enc.en_end_date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d') if pd.notnull(x) else np.nan)
enc[(enc.year >= 2024) & (enc.month >= 1) & (enc.day >= 1)]
```

And here is where the actual issue is happening. I am getting absolutely bombarded with:

```
/example/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/internal.py:1573: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
/example/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/internal.py:1573: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
/example/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/internal.py:1573: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
/example/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/pandas/internal.py:1573: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
```

Hundreds of times. I would just like to turn this off. Any suggestions.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @ABaron I had to roll back my version of Pandas to 1.4.7. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone having this problem, roll back your Pandas versions until the warnings stop, unfortunatley there is no other way to suppress this.

Answer (score 0):

It also works to suppress `FutureWarnings` by using the [`warnings`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) module.

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

For me this worked in Azure Synapse, but it might depend on your specific configuration.

Comment: You can't surpress FutureWarnings for pyspark unfortunatley. You either have to roll back or live with it. I tried this.

Comment: Well, for me this did work, so I thought to just put it here, since for some other people it might work. Will add this disclaimer to my answer